# Delete top second commit using git rebase -i

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, git-commit

I was to delete top second commit using git rebase -i
once it worked fine
The other time it was showing merge conflicts.
I dont know why it was showing merge conflicts while it worked fine earlier.
I have reduced my problem to a simpler one and pasted my commandline log here.
It is self explanatory
I have deleted useless information and only sufficent information is there.

```
user-pc:~$ git log 
* 2baec37 (HEAD -> good, master, bad) test file
* 76816a5 changed .gitignore
user-pc:~$ cat test.cpp 
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        cout << t*t <<endl;
    }
}
user-pc:~$ vim test.cpp 
user-pc:~$ git add .
user-pc:~$ git diff --cached
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;

+int sqr(int t){
+    return t*t;
+}
+
 int main(){
     int t;
     cin>>t;
     while(t--){
-        cout << t*t <<endl;
+        cout << sqr(t) <<endl;
     }
 }
user-pc:~$ git commit -m "added sqr function"
user-pc:~$ vim test.cpp 
user-pc:~$ git add .
user-pc:~$ git diff --cached
 int main(){
     int t;
-    cin>>t;
+    cin>>t;//input
     while(t--){
         cout << sqr(t) <<endl;
     }
user-pc:~$ git commit -m "added comment"
user-pc:~$ git log 
* 6885e9f (HEAD -> good) added comment
* cb119d2 added sqr function
* 2baec37 (master, bad) test file
user-pc:~$ git rebase -i master
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/good.
user-pc:~$ git log 
* 3ca597b (HEAD -> good) added comment
* 2baec37 (master, bad) test file
user-pc:~$ cat test.cpp 
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;//input
    while(t--){
        cout << t*t <<endl;
    }
}
user-pc:~$ It worked :)
user-pc:~$ 
user-pc:~$ 
user-pc:~$ 
user-pc:~$ git checkout bad
user-pc:~$ git log 
* 3ca597b (good) added comment
* 2baec37 (HEAD -> bad, master) test file
user-pc:~$ cat test.cpp 
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        cout << t*t <<endl;
    }
}
user-pc:~$ vim test.cpp 
user-pc:~$ git add .
user-pc:~$ git diff --cached
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;

+int sqr(int t){
+    return t*t;
+}
+
 int main(){
     int t;
     cin>>t;
     while(t--){
-        cout << t*t <<endl;
+        cout << sqr(t) <<endl;
     }
 }
user-pc:~$ git commit -m "sqr func added"
user-pc:~$ vim test.cpp 
user-pc:~$ git add .
user-pc:~$ git diff --cached
     return t*t;
 }

-int main(){
+int main(){//main fun
     int t;
     cin>>t;
     while(t--){
user-pc:~$ git commit -m "comment added"
user-pc:~$ git log 
* 5595440 (HEAD -> bad) comment added
* 77caf57 sqr func added
| * 3ca597b (good) added comment
|/  
* 2baec37 (master) test file
user-pc:~$ git rebase -i master
error: could not apply 5595440... comment added

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 55954408ccb50252bcb22d01f4506fe6696642a6... comment added
user-pc:~$ cat test.cpp 
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

<<<<<<< HEAD
int main(){
=======
int sqr(int t){
    return t*t;
}

int main(){//main fun
>>>>>>> 5595440... comment added
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        cout << t*t <<endl;
    }
}
user-pc:~$ Why is it not deleting content of commit "sqr func added" 
user-pc:~$ I wanted it to be like this :
user-pc:~$ cat test.cpp 
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){//main fun
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        cout << t*t <<endl;
    }
}
user-pc:~$ tell me why it worked for good branch but not for bad branch
```

Comment: No one is going to diff your merge conflicts, but I will comment that it is perfectly possible to have merge conflicts after deleting commits.  You are reapplying the top commits on a new base, effectively making completely new commits.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it worked fine for branch "good" then whats the issue in "bad" branch.

Comment: Git doesn't work this way.  _Either_ of the rebases on these branches could have resulted in merge conflicts.  There is no "good" or "bad" branch from the point of view of Git.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen good and bad are just names given by me to branch. they are just for naming only. my doubt is if it worked for branch1 then why not for branch2 . what is the logical difference that made it behave different

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't understand what rebasing is.  Do you understand that when you deleted that commit, every commit on top of it had to be _reappied_?  Each reapplied commit may yield a conflict, there are no rules per se.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thats the main thing that i am in doubt . I understanding rebasing well. And I understand that the top commit is to be reapplied. but what is that commit doing. simply adding a comment . it should have applied its comment irrespective of the deleted-commit . As it happened in branch "good" case , lower commit got deleted and the upper commit got reapplied. why the same is not happening in this case .

Comment: I do recall that for a merge conflict to trigger in Git, both parents have to make modifications within a certain number of lines of each other (I think 2-3).  This could be why one is giving conflict but not the other.  Though in practice I stand by what I said earlier that you should be prepared for possible conflicts always.

Comment: `git log` output doesn't check out. The root commit suddenly disappeared? Also `git checkout bad; git log` cannot show the commits of `good` if they happened _after_ the bad branch.

Answer (score 0):

Your commit "add comment" adds a comment very close to the "sqr" function. But this function was added in the commit that you dropped. Git plays it safe and delegates the decision to a human user.

Think of it that way: the commit would apply "add comment after "main" 2 lines below `}`". But the curly brace no longer exists, so Git is confused. A human has to decide. It's too easy for computers to make bad (and non-obvious) decisions :)